# why is this removeDuplicate not working?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I making a function that simply removes duplicate strings, so there are only unique strings left:

```
var d = ['a','b','B','C','d','e','f','e'];
d.length; //8


function removeDuplicates(data) {
    var i, j, a, b;
    for(i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
        a = data[i];
        for(j = i; j < data.length; j++) {
            b = data[j];
            if (a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase()) {
                data.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}


removeDuplicates(d)
d.length; //4 ????
```

There were only two duplicates, Only **B**, **e** should have gotten removed.

but I get this:

```
["b", "C", "e", "e"]
```

Comment: Think about what happens to the indices of elements that are after the one you `.splice()` out, and how you might need to adjust your loop counters to allow for that...

Comment: Try to use j = i + 1. For example, i = 0 then j = 0 and data[0] of course equals data[0]

Comment: @AlexPashkin got it.

Comment: That makes sense. @nnnnnn i suppose all elements move one step up. which means everything gets messed up, so redo loop? by using index--?

Comment: Adjusting the index will work. Having the inner loop go backwards would also work, because then the items whose indices change have already been processed.

Comment: going backward probably wont work either, say an array with 4 instances of character A. I'm at index 10, and it's A. I go backward searching until i reach at 7 where there is another A, I delete it, everything moves up. now at next loop ill be going to 9, and Previous A is again present here. Double checking same thing. Now since there were multiple A, there would be like 3 undefined. I was at 10, deleted 3 duplicates, shortening array length, var i  goes from 10 to 9. 9 of course is nothing now just like 7 & 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is coming from the fact that any time i === j you'll have a match, and it'll be removed. In your inner loop, just put a check so that you only do your "remove them if they're equal" in situations where i !== j

Also, as nnn noted in the comments, splicing will mess up the index. The cleanest way to do this is with a filter and an every.

Updated solution below:

```
var d = ['a', 'b', 'B', 'C', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'e'];
var e = ['e','e','e','e'];
// d.length; //8


function removeDuplicates(data) {
    const noDuplicates = data.filter((letter, ogIndex) => {
        return data.every((innerLetter, innerIndex) => {
            if (ogIndex < innerIndex) {
                const check = letter.toLowerCase() !== innerLetter.toLowerCase();
                return check;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        })
    })

    return noDuplicates
}


console.log(removeDuplicates(d));
// ["a", "B", "C", "d", "f", "e"]

console.log(removeDuplicates(e));
// ["e"]
```

Comment: *"I just think it's weird to stop early before the end ;)"* - Whereas I think it would be weird to continue on to the end when you know you don't need to...

Comment: this has same bug that @nnnnn refers to. lets say you have multiple same strings, you check 1 with 2, remove 2, now 3 becomes 2, but now you check 2 with 3, it is not equal. loop finishes but 1 and 2 are the same

Comment: try with this: `d = ['e','e','e','e','e']`

Comment: I was actually thinking about that... it's always tricky to splice on the fly. Instead you could just keep track of the indices to remove and do them after the fact. I'll update the solution.

Comment: Actually.. if you REALLY wanna do this right, you can do it with a filter. I'll write that up instead.

Comment: Updated it with the filter and every. One thing to note, is the check of ogIndex<innerIndex. If you remove that condition, you can get a list of all letters that have no duplicates (a, c, e, f). If you leave it in, it'll only keep one of each as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

With ES6/ES2015, a simple way of getting a list of unique items is to use the new Set data type.

To "unique"-ify an array, just convert it to a set and then back to an array. i.e.

```
[...new Set(originalArray)]
```

(Update: My answer originally used `Array.from(S_E_T)` to convert the set back to an array. I have now changed it to `[...S_E_T]` to do that conversion.)

To do the same in a case-insensitive manner, follow the same logic, but just convert each original array element to its lowercase equivalent before converting that whole array to the set.

To do keep only the first instance of a string of any case (e.g. to keep 'cAt' from ['cAt', 'CaT'] instead of just the all-lowercased 'cat'), first perform the case-insensitive search as above, then get the index of each unique lowercase element from the lowercased un-uniqified original array, then use that index to retrieve the whichever-cased element from the original-cased un-uniqified original array.

```js
const show = msg => {console.log(JSON.stringify(msg))};

const f = (arr) => {
  const arrLC = arr.map(x => x.toLowerCase(x));
  return [...new Set(arrLC)].map(x => arr[arrLC.indexOf(x)])
};

const d1 = ['a','b','B','C','d','e','f','e'];
const d2 = ['e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e'];

show(d1);
show([...new Set(d1)]);
show([...new Set(d1.map(x => x.toLowerCase(x)))]);
show(f(d1));
show('------');
show(d2);
show([...new Set(d2)]);
```

Comment: is it really good way, if you convert from array to set, then set back to array. Also output isn't what i wanted. 2nd call to show outputs character B two times, third call to show alter the character case from upper to lower. It seems too forced.

Comment: So, given an input of `['a','b','B','C','d','e','f','e']` what _do_ you want your output to look like? `['a','b','C','d','e','f']`, i.e. the same as my last output  but the `c/C` still in uppercase?

Comment: actually I am confused, given it's almost at random that case of character would be chosen then it makes no sense to object at all being lowercase. So nvm, it looks good. Although, not sure about performance wise. but that's what a set is